Reverse proxy in front of multiple apps listening on localhost
Scenario
I have two streamlit apps listening on localhost.
Apache is setup as a reverse proxy to handle https connections.
Configuration
Here's the configuration I'm using:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test-01.dharmatech.dev-streamlit-apps.conf:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test-01.dharmatech.dev
    # ServerAlias www.test-01.dharmatech.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test-01.dharmatech.dev
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /hello-1/(.*)         ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /hello-1/(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass        /hello-1 http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
    ProxyPassReverse /hello-1 http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1

    ProxyPass        /hello-1 ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
    ProxyPassReverse /hello-1 ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /hello-2/(.*)         ws://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /hello-2/(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass        /hello-2 http://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2
    ProxyPassReverse /hello-2 http://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2

    ProxyPass        /hello-2 ws://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2
    ProxyPassReverse /hello-2 ws://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/test-01.dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test-01.dharmatech.dev/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

So we have the following:
https://test-01.dharmatech.dev/hello-1   ->   http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
https://test-01.dharmatech.dev/hello-2   ->   http://127.0.0.1:8512/hello-2

Question
The actual lines used to setup the reverse proxy for an app are these:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /hello-1/(.*)         ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /hello-1/(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /hello-1 http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
ProxyPassReverse /hello-1 http://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1

ProxyPass        /hello-1 ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1
ProxyPassReverse /hello-1 ws://127.0.0.1:8511/hello-1

I put these together by looking at various examples found online.
As you can see, the app uses websockets.
So far, this seems to be working OK.
Is this the recommended approach for setting up a reverse proxy for an app that uses websockets?
Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome. If there's a better or more idiomatic way to express this, I'd be interested in hearing about it.
Side note: I'm open to using other tools. So if some other tool like nginx, haproxy, etc. is more appropriate for a setup like this, feel free to suggest that as well.
